# Can i use react-dropzone-uploader with Cloudinary?

Tags: reactjs, image, cloudinary, dropzone, react-dropzone

I need to use RDU with cloudinary is it possible or is there another solution similar to RDU to use with cloudinary? i need to preview images and delete an image from the preview before upload

Answer (score -1):

It should be possible.  Taking the example [here](https://github.com/fortana-co/react-dropzone-uploader) you could use the Cloudinary upload API in the submit method

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference